# How to make form that allow users to input a mix of repeated and unique data in google form and then send the result to google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I want to make a google form where the user can submit data like the example below[image: sample table]

The invoice and invoice date for each form will be the same while the rest of the data will be different. Is there a way to make the form in google sheet where the user can:

1. input invoice and invoice date only 1 time while the rest is manually inputted
2. send the result to google sheet with the same format as the table above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible in Google Forms currently, as each response must be written to a pre-determined row.

One way this might be achieved is by using a single instance of your form for each item in the invoice. Each response can then be appended to the existing sheet; although not an ideal solution, this is probably the best you will get with Google Sheets. See an example of how to do this [here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/how-to-use-google-forms-as-an-expense-tracker/)

Comment: I suspected that as well. Unfortunately, submitting a form instance for each item is not effective as there are times when the amount of items are in thousands